# C++ How to change the text in a TextBox from outside the class

Tags: c++, api, textbox

First, I'm a newbie in C++. I'm implementing some of my finite element Matlab code in C++. I'm doing fine when writing data to the console, but now I'm trying to do a very very simple API with Visual Studio. I've created a CLR project with a Form with 1 push button and a TextBox inside. The code for the Form is automatically generated by Visual Studio.

I'm trying to create an API that performs as follows.

1) When I hit the button a function that is outside the class is executed.
2) After the function is executed, the result of the execution is printed in the textbox.

I don't want to put the function inside the Form class, because this function is expected to grow to a full FEM code. My problem is that I can't set the Text Property of the textbox with something like: `this->TextBox1->Text = "Result is 22"`. Is there a way to do that easily?

My code is organized as follows.

```
// programa.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"  // (cointains the Form1 Class)
#include <iostream>

using namespace programa;
using namespace std;

[STAThreadAttribute]


void calcular(int a) {  
    .... // Calculation
    .... // Some method to set Text of Text Box
}


int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why C++/CLI ? This kind of application should be written in C# ... or if you want to keep it C++, then without .NET Framework...

Comment: @LihO: *"Why C++/CLI ?"* - Because deterministic destructor calls are nice enough of a feature to dump *<insert random .NET language>* in favor of C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your `calcular` function a pointer to the text box or something similar.  I don't know the correct type for your textbox, but the code will look something like:

```
void calcular(int a, TextBox* textbox) {  
    .... // Calculation
    textbox->Text = "Result is 22";
}
```

You also will probably need to call a `setText` function or something similar, rather than directly modifying the property.

Comment: Note that sending pointer to some GUI element (button, text box, label, ...) within your application is like spreading virus... this way leads to quite messy code

Comment: Besides, this will cause problems if `calcular` is in a different thread. Most GUI components are not thread-safe

Comment: @Desolator That's why I was suggesting a setText call if it exists, but I don't know .NET, so I'm not sure if a threadsafe setText (or any setText) function exists.

Comment: @LihO Good point.  I'm not sure the question is really on good architecture, but more just "how do I get this to work real quick so I can good back to my FEM research".  "Research code" is not a compliment ;)

Comment: @Soverman: Do you want to create good software or software that just "somehow works"?

Comment: @LihO Just trying to provide the answer I think will be most helpful to the questioner given the stated level of programming experience and a presumed limited interest in architecting GUI programs (inferred from the fact that "API" seems to be used in place of "GUI" in the question).

Comment: OK, Soverman and @LihO are rigth. My programming experience is near zero. I don't know if to include the textbox as an argument to calcular because in the future I will need to set more than one text box. My question should have been posted as: I need to create a GUI to control my FEA software (approximatele 20K lines of code), I know I should give this work to a software engineer but I don't have much to pay. The GUI need to control the execution of the software and give information of the time stepping, residuals and iterations. Not big deal. Now, which is the best way to that?

Comment: @Martin You're probably best off inverting the control flow here.  Rather than trying to have FEM code which is aware of the GUI, make sure your FEM code exposes an interface which provides all the control over it you need.  In other words, change calcular to return a string if that's what it logically does.  Then in your GUI code call into calcular/etc and use the returned string to update your text box.  You may also need to look into threading / events if you want a GUI that doesn't freeze up during calculations, but that gets more complicated, and maybe freezes are OK for your application.

Comment: Thanks @Soverman ! I understand your point, I've been reading stuff about the MVC pattern and now I'm understanding how to organize the code. I think that this is going to help me a lot, maybe for you the advice may sound obvious but for someone with little experience it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just an advice never never and never invoke gui in your algorithm, the best way is to create a class for your algo where the calcul is done, another class as controler.

In the main method you create an instance of algo and another for the controler, and you give to the controler the form1 instance and the algo instance, the controler will invoke the algo and after refresh the form.

Comment: Issam is referring to the "Model-View-Controller" design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Thanks Issam ! Do you think I could implement it without being 6 months learning the details?

Comment: not 6 months , maybe 6 minutes is sufficient :), what you have to do is to create a class(CCalculator) and move Calculate to it, Create a Class CCalculatorControler who has two fields CCalculator m_calculator, and Form1 m_form, it just a restructuration of your code.